# Using Websecurity, upon login Role information doesn't seem to be available

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, simplemembership

My first question here. For an MVC 4 CMS application that I am building, I am making use of the SimpleMembersshipProvider. In it, I have users that are assigned to specific roles. Upon login, I want to check what role these users have, and then redirect them to their specific part of the application.

So when the user logs in, I check using:

```
if (ModelState.IsValid && WebSecurity.Login(model.UserName, model.Password, persistCookie: model.RememberMe))
{
  if (User.IsInRole("Organisation"))
  {
    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Organisation");
  }
}
```

This never works the first time around, but as soon as I type in the URL after the code has executed, or if I do this a second time, it works perfectly. Is the Role information not available upon login? Is there another way I need to handle this perhaps?

Thanks for your answers and my appologies if this is an easy question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to write that if section after redirection. roles don't work before page refresh.